# How to drag and drop on WPF Grid C#

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop

I am creating a program that allows the user to drag and drop nodes and edges onto a grid to create a weighted graph to find the minimum spanning tree but I am really new to WPF and quite new to c# and I am stuck on how to drag and drop things onto a grid. Do I need to create lots of cells with individual borders or something I am really stuck.[make the grid like this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Agazn.png)

I tried finding the position on the grid before adding lot of cells onto the grid but I couldn't figure anything out. I added lots of cells to the grid like the image above but I'm stuck on how to add borders to each individual cell and it seems really impractical ass there are 400 cells or do I even need the borders in each cell to able to drag and drop?

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            
        <!--menu-->
        <controls:Menu />
        <!--Content-->
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Stroke="Black" Fill="Transparent" />
        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        </Grid>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <!--Buttons-->
        </Grid>
        <!--Items-->
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="2" Fill="Transparent" />
        <ItemBar:DragItems Margin="0,-40,0,0" Width="800" Height="40" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Row="2"/>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="0*"/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <ColumnDefinition Width="253*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="438*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="126*"/>

            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        </Grid>
        <!--Result-->
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="3" Fill="Gray" Stroke="Black"/>
        <Grid Grid.Row="3">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="170" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <!--Outputs-->
            <Label Content="Critial Path" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="150" Height="30" FontSize="16" Name="ResultBox" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Grid.Column="1"/>

        </Grid>
        
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This is the XAML for my MainWindow

```
namespace Simulation.View.Display.Content.GraphCreation
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for DragItems.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class DragItems : UserControl
    {
        public DragItems()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void NodeCircle_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            {
                DragDrop.DoDragDrop(nodeCircle, nodeCircle, DragDropEffects.Move);
            }
        }

        private void Grid_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            double DropPosY = Grid.GetColumn(itemBar);       
            double DropPosX = Grid.GetRow(itemBar);
            
            


        }
    }
```

This is my drag and drop c# code as of currently being stuck.

Comment: Are you *sure* you want to use a grid? A canvas with, with some code to "snap" positions, sounds more appropriate to me.